# Python Merge Some Columns of a Dataframe in to a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merging-data

I have a data frame as shown in the image below. The first column is Date/Time while the other columns are voltage values. Only a single value column will have a voltage in any row. I would like to merge the voltage columns into a single column. I could do this with a cumbersome for-loop and I am hoping for some panda merge that would do this. I have looked at many merge related posts and could not find, or did not recognize, a solution to this problem. Any help for this would be greatly appreciated.
[Dataframe with Date/time in column 1 and values in columns 2 - 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4etx.png)

Comment: Can you provide some pythonic sample data of both what you expect it to look like vs what it currently is? Using only a screenshot makes it difficult to help trouble shoot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is a very scaled down version of what the dataframe looks like, followed by the desired output.                                                                                                         
 DATE  Voltage1 Voltage2 Voltage3
1/2/2022 100  NaN  NaN
1/3/2022 NaN  NaN  150
1/4/2022 125  NaN  NaN
1/5/2022 NaN  130  NaN

Desired Output
DATE  Voltage
1/2/2022 100
1/3/2022 150
1/4/2022 125
1/5/2022 130                                                                                                                          Deleting the other voltage cols from the df I can do.

Comment: I thought I had formatted the comment so that the Dates and Voltages appeared in separate columns. Sorry that this came out so messed up.